# How do you reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: usb

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

I don't know how to open the Installer to get those options.

Also I don't have a CD drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the ubuntu installer, you need to create a Live USB.

Instructions for [windows are here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), and [ubuntu here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Then you change the BIOS boot order to be the USB first. Here, item 3 should be item 1.

[image]

Boot it, and you will see the screen that says "Try or Install".

[image]

Click install, then choose "Erase Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstall".

[image]